# R: How do you use ncol() dynamically in lapply?

Tags: r, matrix, apply, lapply

I am trying to add a row `NewRow` to each matrix in a list `mylist`. `NewRow` should be a vector of integers from 1 until the end of the row. Each matrix in `mylist` has a different number of columns, so the last number in the `NewRow` vector isn't constant, it has to be dynamic. These are my attempts:

```
mylist.with.new.row <- lapply(mylist, rbind, NewRow = 1:ncol())
mylist.with.new.row <- lapply(mylist, rbind, NewRow = 1:ncol(mylist))
```

Neither work because `ncol()` can't be empty, but also can't just be `ncol(mylist)` because it has to be dynamic.
I assume this can be done with a loop but I'm hoping someone knows a quicker way.
Thanks!

Comment: If you need a value from the iteration, you'll need to use a function. `lapply(mylist, function(x) rbind(x, NewRow = 1:ncol(x)))`. At least I think that's what you want. It would be more clear if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and the desired output. Another alternative might be: `Map(rbind, mylist, lapply(lengths(mylist), seq.int))`

Comment: That works, thank you!